# NodeJS - Compile shared cpp libraries in GCP Cloud Functions

Tags: c++, node.js, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

### In general

When you're installing dependencies with `npm install` (or `yarn`) locally, any native (c++) libraries inside are automatically compiled.

However after deploying to Cloud Functions you may get similar error:

```
Error: *.so: cannot open shared object file
```

*So how can they be used in a Cloud function?*

### Specific example

*I think this question applies to any c++ libraries & node dependencies, but I can show you my specific use case.*

I'm trying to run tensorflow.js in a cloud function, but the `tfjs-node` package includes a shared library `libtensorflow.so` 
Installing locally using `yarn` automatically runs `node-gyp` scripts and compiles everything needed.

However after deploying the GCP Cloud function and calling it, results in error:

> Error: libtensorflow.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Full logs are hosted in [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/32F7GMKZ).

And the question here is again: *How to compile the library and solve the error?*

Comment: It might not be supported.  I know you can build a full binary and deploy it with your functions, but I've never heard of anyone depending on an npm build of a shared library for use in Cloud Functions.

Comment: @DougStevenson What you mean by full binary and can building that binary resolve the problem in my use case?

Comment: Full binary meaning something you would execute directly to do what you want. A whole new process, not loading a library.

Comment: @DougStevenson May I ask you to post that last bits as an answer of your own?

Comment: @Mangu It's not really an answer to the stated question.  It's merely an observation.